# R reshape tall to wide with many to many relationship table

Tags: r, pivot, reshape

I have a table with parent and his or her child's info(name, grade, age). One child can have multiple parents and one parents can have multiple children. I want to reshape the table so each row will be an unique parent with all his or her children's information labeled as .1, ,2 etc.

Original Table:

| ParentID | ChildN | ChildGrade | ChildAge | HouseholdID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | 10 | 21 | a |
| 2 | x | 10 | 21 | a |
| 3 | z | 12 | 23 | b |
| 1 | y | 13 | 24 | a |
| 2 | y | 13 | 24 | a |
| 3 | t | 15 | 26 | b |
| 4 | g | 16 | 27 | c |

Goal:

| ParentID | ChildN.1 | ChildGrade.1 | ChildAge.1 | ChildN.2 | ChildGrade.2 | ChildAge.2 | HouseholdID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | 10 | 21 | y | 13 | 24 | a |
| 2 | x | 10 | 21 | y | 13 | 24 | a |
| 3 | z | 12 | 23 | t | 15 | 26 | b |
| 4 | g | 16 | 27 | NA | NA | NA | c |

I want to know how to achieve this in R. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve your desired result using `tidyr::pivot_wider` by first adding an id column for the children:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df |> 
  group_by(ParentID) |> 
  mutate(child_id = row_number()) |> 
  pivot_wider(values_from = c("ChildN", "ChildGrade",   "ChildAge"), names_from = "child_id",
              names_glue = "{.value}.{child_id}")
#> # A tibble: 4 × 8
#> # Groups:   ParentID [4]
#>   ParentID HouseholdID ChildN.1 ChildN.2 ChildGrade.1 ChildGrade.2 ChildAge.1
#>      <int> <chr>       <chr>    <chr>           <int>        <int>      <int>
#> 1        1 a           x        y                  10           13         21
#> 2        2 a           x        y                  10           13         21
#> 3        3 b           z        t                  12           15         23
#> 4        4 c           g        <NA>               16           NA         27
#> # … with 1 more variable: ChildAge.2 <int>
```

Comment: I think it gets closer. I think the child_id serves a way to tally how many children each parent has? I don't know what but the number is off for some parents when I tried your code using the real data.   <- Oh, it seems that I have many NA for parent ID in the original table which contributes to the large number. I will give it another shot. Thanks. It looks very promising.